# Is there a way to let the user create a cron entry without opening nano

Tags: bash, administration

Is there a way to create a cron entry with bash where the user only have to enter the command to execute and the script does the rest.

Create cron file if it isn't already created 
Set the execution time.

Thank you to investigate.

Comment: Create empty temp file, launch editor and upon save you process the contents and create cron entry.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
crontab -l > ./my.cron
: manipulate ./my.cron somehow without editing
crontab ./my.cron
```

I'm not aware of a tool that is a "wizard" for creating cron entries.

If your question is really about using nano, then set your `VISUAL` environment variable to your preferred editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want. The normal way of creating a crontab is to run `crontab -e`. Then, the user will "only have to enter the command to execute and the script does the rest". All the user has to do is set the time and the command to be run. How could it be simpler?

It is impossible to have `cron` set the time automatically, how can it know when you would like the command to run? Do you mean you want to create a crontab that has a *default* time?
If so, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time="0 5 * * 1" ## 5 a.m every week 

read -p "Enter the command you wish cron to run:" comm 

file=`mktemp` && echo "$time $comm" > $file && crontab $file && rm $file
```

You can save that as, for example,  `/usr/local/bin/make_crontab.sh`.

---

Alternatively, if all you want is to not use `nano`, change your `$EDITOR` variable. Personally I use `emacs` so I have this line in my `.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR='/usr/bin/emacs';
```